# Login to External Website (PHP) using Salesforce Credentials

Tags: apex, community, salesforcedx

I have a site made in PHP, all my users are using Salesforce as well. I want to show Salesforce login on my website where users can provide their Salesforce credentials and then Salesforce could redirect me about user information (either login or not) so that I could create a session on my site. They don't need to provide separate credentials for my site. Also, users will be created in Salesforce and after creation, it will send all information to my site as well.
I tried Auth Provider to make Login flow but somehow it's now working.
Could the Identity provider/Service provider help me do so?

Comment: Yes, Identity provider would help you out. You could have a "login with Salesforce", something like the "Login with Linked-in" they have in Trailhead. The user is re-directed to salesforce, where they need to log-in, and then redirected back to your site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally not a PHP person. But I do know there is a well-established long-standing PHP tool out there that uses OAuth for signing into Salesforce. This uses precisely the architecture you describe: workbench is a client that auths using your Salesforce user information, no user data is stored by the app itself, and all data is accessed as/when needed via API connections.

Login seems to be in [this](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/d4eb1298798503665ada95754be7aa86f34dfcd7/workbench/context/WorkbenchContext.php#L96) script. Maybe with that as a starting point, someone who knows PHP could use that as a jumping off point to learn how workbench does auth and use that in your own app.